# How to encrypt data while we take mysqldump?

Tags: encryption, mysql, mysql5

I need to encrypt data while we take mysqldump from database through command prompt. My OS is windows7. Please help me.

Comment: There is an idiom in English called "taking a dump". See http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Taking%20a%20dump

Comment: But he is a learner :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just pipe the dump output directly though your encryption tool?
ie:

```
mysqldump mydb | some-encryption-tool.sh
```

btw, the only reason I suggested piping directly through an encryption tool is to the (unsafe) plain-text version never exists on disk, which is the only interpretation of the question that makes sense. Otherwise, just save the dump to a file and encrypt it - there is nothing to "answer".

Comment: sorry I can't understand what you mean?

Comment: rather than send the mysql dump to a file, send it into the encryption tool

Comment: It would be a better idea to dump it to file first, so the encryption can be verified (but you end up with 3 copies of the instead of just 2). Impossible to advise what a suitable encryption tool would be without knowing what OS this runs on.

Comment: Hi my os is windows. Does it possible to do in windows command prompt? If yes can you please suggest me some encryption tools